# Getting Read Timed Out Exception for Google Adwords

Tags: google-api, google-ads-api

We are using Google Adwords APIs (v201710) to get customer information, adGroup and campaign information and to download reports.

We are now frequently facing **java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out** exception. Our threads are getting hanged because of this.

Any idea why this is happening?

**StackTrace:**

```
{http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at com.zoho.instrument.MIInputStream.read(MIInputStream.java:29)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:983)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:940)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.readHeadersFromSocket(HTTPSender.java:583)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:143)
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at com.google.api.ads.adwords.axis.v201710.mcm.CustomerServiceSoapBindingStub.getCustomers(CustomerServiceSoapBindingStub.java:698)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor228.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.google.api.ads.common.lib.soap.SoapClientHandler.invoke(SoapClientHandler.java:100)
    at com.google.api.ads.common.lib.soap.axis.AxisHandler.invokeSoapCall(AxisHandler.java:234)
    at com.google.api.ads.common.lib.soap.SoapServiceClient.callSoapClient(SoapServiceClient.java:63)
    at com.google.api.ads.common.lib.soap.SoapServiceClient.invoke(SoapServiceClient.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy69.getCustomers(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: probably network issue as we're not facing the same issue with same `v201710` version for downloading reports